# Using Bash to cURL a website and grep for keywords

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, grep

I'm trying to write a script that will do a few things in the following order:

1. cURL websites from a list of urls contained within a "url_list.txt" (new-line delineated) file.
2. For each website in the list, I want to grep that website looking for keywords contained within a "keywords.txt" (new-line delineated) file.
3. I want to finish by printing to the terminal in the following format (or something similar):

   $URL (that contained match) : $keyword (that made the match)

It needs to be able to run in Ubuntu (GNU grep, etc.)

It does not need to be cURL and grep; as long as the functionality is there.

So far I've got:

```
#!/bin/bash
keywords=$(cat ./keywords.txt)
urllist=$(cat ./url_list.txt)
for url in $urllist; do
        content="$(curl -L -s "$url" | grep -iF "$keywords" /dev/null)"
        echo "$content"
done
```

But for some reason, no matter what I try to tweak or change, it keeps failing to one degree or another.

How can I go about accomplishing this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
keywords="$(<./keywords.txt)"
while IFS= read -r url; do
    curl -L -s "$url" | grep -ioF "$keywords" |
        while IFS= read -r keyword; do
            echo "$url: $keyword"
        done
done < ./url_list.txt
```

What did I change:

- I used `$(<./keywords.txt)` to read the `keywords.txt`. This does not rely on an external program (`cat` in your original script).
- I changed the `for` loop that loops over the url list, into a `while` loop. This guarentees that we use `Θ(1)` memory (i.e. we don't have to load the entire url list in memory).
- I remove /dev/null from grep. `grep`ing from `/dev/null` alone is meaningless, since it will find nothing there. Instead, I invoke `grep` with no arguments so that it filters its `stdin` (which happens to be the output of `curl` in this case).
- I added the `-o` flag for `grep` so that it outputs only the matched keyword.
- I removed the subshell where you were capturing the output of `curl`. Instead I run the command directly and feed its output to a while loop. This is necessary because we might get more than keyword match per url.

Comment: You could probably use `grep -ioF -f ./keywords.txt`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!
One question,
What if there is multiple matches for the same keyword on the same URL?
Is there a way to unique the output?

Comment: @Probie Then you could do something like `curl -L -s "$url" | grep -ioF "$keywords" | sort | uniq |`.

Comment: @redneb Duh... Thanks!

Comment: or just `sort -u` ;-) . Good luck to all.